# How to get significance level for ranked features?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, feature-selection, feature-extraction

I am aware of below approaches of feature selection

**a)** Feature Importance methods which are available in tree based models like `Random Forest` and `Xgboost`,`GradientBoost` etc.

**b)** `statsmodel.logistic regression` which in it's summary output provide us the results which contains whether `variables are significant or not (P-value)`

**c)**  `SelectKbest` which uses `ANOVA`, `Chi-square` etc to compute the influence of `input variable` on `target attribute`

But unfortunately with methods `b` and `c`, it doesn't consider the feature interaction. Am I right? It works by considering each column to the target variable

Whereas with methods `a` it returns the ranking but we aren't sure about whether they are significant or not.

Is there anyway to know from `Feature Importance` whether the Features are significant or not? I understand `features occurring in top 4-5 places could be significant but is there anyway to test/validate this`?

Or is it like I pick each feature (out of say top 20 assuming they have a role) from feature importance result and do a `SelectKbest` test or `statsmodel summary`?

How can I know that the features that I select from `Feature importance` model are significant?

Comment: Hi, I was trying to add significance to the predictive features/add interpretive ability to my model. I am sharing this here as it is a related post. For which I did the below. can you help me with this post https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65502/how-to-interpret-shapley-force-plot-for-feature-importance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. univariate feature importance** (*that is **c)** in your list)*

You are correct. Univariate statistics to estimate feature importance does not capture feature interactions. But they are fast and simple.

**2. model-based feature importance** *(that are **a)** and **b)** in your list)*

On the other hand model-based feature importance estimates can capture interactions as long as the model is capable of doing so (see "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python"; Mueller, Guido; 2017; p. 238/239). Which is not the case for linear regression.

For model-based feature importance estimates using trees there are ways to derive p-values. And at least R does have some implementations for that. Have a look at section "2.5 Importance testing procedures" in this paper [The revival of the Gini importance?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6198850/pdf/bty373.pdf).

Comment: Got it. thanks.

Comment: no prob. Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Is there any python package to do this?

Comment: Can you also share the `R` package name that does this? or tutorial if any. I am new to ML and any step by step tutorial will help

Comment: @SSMK Have a look at the vita package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vita/index.html . Also the authors of the paper I linked mention that the Ranger package has some implementations.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1.** *But unfortunately with methods b and c, it doesn't consider the feature interaction. Am I right? It works by considering each column to the target variable*

**None** of the methods will take feature interactions into account [See here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0031320315000850)

For a seperate discussion of feature interactions [see here](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/interaction.html)

**Question 2.** *Is there anyway to know from Feature Importance whether the Features are significant or not? I understand features occurring in top 4-5 places could be significant but is there anyway to test/validate this*

**2 ways:**

a) formally you can extend permutation importance to include p-values. Look at [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/26/10/1340/193348)

b) informally do cross-validation while performing some feature-selection